# copy all except first row into new csv file python

Tags: python, csv

I generate several csv files each day, and I'm trying to write a python script that will open each csv file, one by one, rewrite the csv to a new location and fill in the mission information that is in the filename.

I've been able to cobble together separate python scripts that can do most of it, but I'm hitting brick walls.

each CSV has a standard filename:
"Number_Name_Location.csv"

Row 1 has a header that labels each column, Name, Location, Date etc, and each .csv can have n number of pre-filled in rows.

what I'm trying to automate is the following steps:

1. Opens the 1st .csv in the “/ToParse” folder
2. Fill in the remaining details for all rows, which is gathered from the filename itself.

   - Column A: Number
   - Column B: Date of Parsing
   - Column k: Name
   - Column L: Location
3. writes a new csv in the folder “/Parsed” w
4. continue to parse the next .csv until no .csv are in the "/ToParse" folder
5. move all orginal parsed files to /Parsed/Original

below is the cobbled together code, which is overwriting the header row,
How can i adjust the code to ignore the first row in the csv it's opening and just copy from rows 1 onward

```
import glob
import csv
from datetime import date

with open('Parsed/output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for filename in glob.glob('*.csv'):
        with open(filename, newline='') as f_input:
            csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
            filename_parts = filename.split("_")
            #print(filename_parts[0]) 

            for row in csv_input:
                row[0] = filename_parts[0]
                row[1] = date.today()
                row[10] = filename_parts[1]
                row[11] = filename_parts[2]
                csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide a minimal sample of code that is causing you trouble.

Comment: What have you done yourself and what concrete problem do you face?

Comment: Add the code you have developed so far to get some opinions. Besides that, i'm not sure you would need anything more complicated than a for loop.

Comment: Thanks all, i have updated the original post to include my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `open(filename, newline='')` seems strange to me. Are you sure you want `newline=''`?

You can skip the first line by manually doing `f_input.readline()` before the for loop. This will read (=skip) the first line and the for-loop will start on the next line.

Or you could do `for row in csv_input[1:]` but I am not sure that works and cannot test it right now. (`[1:]` means skip the first item in any list-like variable (formally called: `Iterable`) )

Comment: " Are you sure you want newline=''? ", my understanding is that newline='' is the universal new line character for CSV files, so it doens't care if its a \n or \r

Comment: Oh, okay. You may be right, I've never seen that before :)